# pandas groupby-agg inconsistent about keeping group columns without as_index param

Tags: python, pandas, types

Grouping on 2 columns of a 2-column DataFrame keeps the columns as columns:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]})
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

[3 rows x 2 columns]
>>> df.groupby(['a','b']).agg(sum)
     a  b
a b      
1 4  1  4
2 5  2  5
3 6  3  6

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

But grouping on 2 columns of a 3-column DataFrame turns those columns to indexes:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6],'c':[7,8,9]})
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9

[3 rows x 3 columns]
>>> df.groupby(['a','b']).agg(sum)
     c
a b   
1 4  7
2 5  8
3 6  9

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

Passing `as_index=False` consistently returns columns:

```
>>> df.groupby(['a','b'], as_index=False).agg(sum)
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Is the best practice here to always use as_index=False so people reading your code know what to expect?

Comment: You seem to be confused here, the columns part of the index because you grouped on them, you called sum on the this and the net result is virtually the same df but columns 'a' and 'b' as the index. In the latter case it does sum again but as you have duplicate rows then you see a difference in the final df.

Comment: I'm not sure what default behavior should be there, but the standard situation is that you aren't summing (or whatever) the same columns you are grouping by, so your example seems very artificial to me.  That's not meant as a criticism of the question, I'm just not sure exactly what practical situation you are concerned with.  I think that if the `as_index=False` output is indeed what you want here, then yes you ought to be specifying it explicitly b/c I wouldn't expect it implicitly.

Comment: To restate slightly:  your results for the 3-column case are as expected.  If you like the `as_index=False` results, you should specify that explicitly.  The 2-column case seems strange, but it's a strange thing to even be trying.  It appears as if pandas is defaulting to `as_index=False` there but not clear why.  The results that @maxymoo reports for the 2 column are what I would have expected prior to seeing the results.

Answer (score 1):

The first behaviour is confusing to me and maybe is a deprecated feature? On Python 3.4.1, Pandas 0.16.1 and I get the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]})
df.groupby(['a','b']).agg(sum)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Comment: I get the same result as you (empty dataframe) in 0.16.1 and python 2.7. I'd tend to agree that the first behavior for the questioner is confusing.  It seem like the result ought to be an empty dataframe as you find with 0.16.1.

Comment: hmm -- I'm using pandas 0.13.1. I'm guessing I'm dealing with a bug that's long-since fixed. I'm going to vote to close the question.